# Let $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Find $F_Z(z)$ in terms of $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$

Tags: probability

I think I have the answer to this, I just used independence, but could someone answer to make sure

Let $Z=\min(X,Y)$ Find $F_Z(z)$ in terms of $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$

My basic work goes as follows:

$$F_{Z}(z)=\Pr(Z < z)=\Pr(\min(X,Y) < z)=\Pr(X < z)\cap \Pr(Y > z)=\Pr(X < z)(1-\Pr(Y < z))$$

The last two steps are the one I was confused about

Comment: Are you saying that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Also, could you explain what you have done?

Comment: We'd be happy to check your work, but in order to do that, we'll need to *see it*. Please post your answer.

Comment: The question does not expressly say that X and Y are independent, but the context of the chapter it is in means they have to be independent so I am assuming they are. My basic work goes as follos:

Comment: Fz(z)=Pr(Z<z)=Pr(Min(X,Y)<z)=Pr(X<z)intersect Pr(y>z)=Pr(X<z)(1-Pr(Y<z)) The last two steps are the one I was confused about

Comment: Yurindd: I included your elaboration on your question in the post itself.

Comment: Just a remark, but you get an answer that's not symmetrical in $X$ and $Y$; is that plausible, in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I was giving a complete answer but it seems like everyone is wanting you learn. Then just a hint:
$$\min(X,Y)\geq z \iff X\geq z \cap \ Y\geq z$$